# Destroy and replace DataTable using jquery on resize not working

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to dynamically change the `DataTable` and it seems that it's not working when I **destroy**  and **replace** a `DataTable`. It gives me an error of **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** . Here is my code:

```
  $(window).on('resize load', function () {
var width = $(window).width();
if (width < 720) {

    var table = $('#example').destroy(); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "scrollY": "300px",
            "scrollX": "100%",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
} else {

    var table = $('#example').destroy();//Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

    $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you include this script? Top of bottom page?

Answer (score 0):

Your var table points to null as the datatable is initialized after that line. You should initialize datatables at the top of the script.

I assume that you are using the latest version of datatables from https://cdn.datatables.net/

Example

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    //options to initialize your datatable properly
                });
    $(window).on('resize load', function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 720) {

            table.destroy();

            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                "scrollY": "300px",
                    "scrollX": "100%",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging": false
            });
            new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(table);
        } else {

            table.destroy();

            $('#example').DataTable({
                responsive: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```